# How do I set a variable's value to data I received from Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I have a function to get a list of movies in JSON format, as follows:

```
var size: Int = 0

func getMovies() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie", parameters: ["sort_by" : "popularity", "api_key" : "secret api key"])
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                self.json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                self.arraySize = self.json["results"].count
                for num in 0...self.arraySize - 1 {
                    let x = self.json["results"][num]["popularity"]
                    self.movieArray.append(x.double!)
                }
                self.movieArray.sortInPlace()
                for num in 0...self.arraySize - 1 {
                    let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: num, inSection: 0)
                    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path)
                    cell?.textLabel?.text = (self.findMovieByPopularity(self.movieArray[num]) + ":    " + String(self.movieArray[num]))
                }
                size = self.json["results"].count
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Towards the end of `case .Success:` I try and set the variable `size`, which I declared outside of the function, to the length of one property in the JSON. However, when I use this variable outside of the switch, its value is still 0.

How could  I set `size` to the length of the property and also be able to use it outside of the function?

Comment: It is an asynchronous response. Size is not set until after the response is complete. Set a breakpoint on that statement to ensure that it is being set properly. If it's still zero, then perhaps the result is incorrect. But your code is fine. I would however pass self into the closure using [unowned self] or [weak self] to prevent a retain cycle.

Comment: Under what category in the Thread would I check to see if the value is being set properly?

Comment: Size is set as an instance property, right? Then you can set it using self.size and it will be available outside of the function. You can double check it by adding a breakpoint on that statement itself

Comment: You may try to return it in the completion handler and use it there so you will get the value of the size when the asynchronous call gets completed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a completion handler and assign the value in a closure like so:

```
func getMovies(completion: (aSize: Int) -> ()) {

let someSize: Int! 
//your code
case .Success:
               //your code
               let x = self.json["results"][num]["popularity"]
                    self.movieArray.append(x.double!)
                someSize = self.json["results"].count
                }
  completion(aSize: someSize)
//your code
```

and then when you want to call it in someother function call like so:

```
getMovies {numSize in

self.size = numSize

}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. When I call getMovies I can't use `size` outside of the brackets because it remains 0. Although when I `print(size)` inside the brackets it is 20 like it's supposed to be. (The problem is that I need to return the value of `size` in a function.

Comment: `var size` is a `global` variable, as you've put it in your code here, correct? And it is initialised to 0. And when `Alamofire` finished fetching the data, you update it like I've shown you. Did you try this? Did it still say 0 when you printed it out?

Comment: 'getMovies {numSize in
            
            self.size = numSize
            print(self.size)
            
        }
        print(size)' 

This is the code I ran to call getMovies(), the 'print' inside the brackets printed 20 while the one outside the brackets printed 0.

Comment: What's the output? 0?

Comment: Yes, it appears that the value of size is only 20 inside the brackets. (Thank you in advance by the way for all the support.)